# Attach ref to Reanimated ScrollView to access .scrollTo

Tags: react-native, react-native-reanimated

Using react-native-reanimated v1.

I have created a snack reproducing this issue - https://snack.expo.io/@noitidart/reanimated-scroll-view-ref

I have created a reanimatable component out of ScrollView like this:

```
import { ScrollView } from 'react-native-gesture-handler';
import Reanimated from 'react-native-reanimated';

const ReanimatedScrollView = Reanimated.createAnimatedComponent(ScrollView);
```

When I render it I want to get a ref to it so I can do `ref.current.scrollTo()`. However the ref is coming back without `scrollTo` on it. Here is my code:

```
const ref = useRef();

const scrollToFoo = () => {
   if (ref.current) {
       ref.current.scrollTo({ y: 100 });
   }
}

return (
<ReanimatedScrollView ref={ref} />
)
```

If I do this with a regular ScrollView, `ref.current` properly has `scrollTo` on it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `getNode()` to get access to the component:

```
ref.current.getNode().scrollTo({ y: 100 });
```

Comment: It seems getNode is not available. I was able to to do `ref.current._component.scrollTo` it was weird.